# Retrieve Column 1 value from VBA ComboBox after using "combobox.value =" to modify selected index value

Tags: vba, combobox

Hello I am working with VBA and I have run into a strange situation. I am hoping that someone out there has run into the same thing and can give me a little help. In my program, there is a 2 column combo box that has it's value set to a string. The value is set like this:

```
ComboBox1.Value = "this_string"
```

Initially this ComboBox has 2 legit columns. I am able to confirm this by using the Immediate Window Later in code the first column of that combo box is checked. For example:
`value =    ComboBox1.Column(0)`

But the code breaks here. I get this error:

> Could not get the Column property. Invalid property array index.

After the value assignment. I can no longer get any Column values. Why is this?

Thank you for your help,
Billy

Comment: Shouldn’t be the issue but Columns is 0-based so to get first column you want column(0).

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Before the values was set I was able to use Column(0) and Column(1) to retrieve values but "after" it was set, I am no longer able to use those properties to get anything. I just get the invalid index error. I need to know why this is happening.

Comment: Then you have to dig into what happens in the piece of code between the last code line you can get the combobox columns correctly and the first code line where you can not: step through your code (F8) and use Immediate Window (CTRL-G to pop it out) to query relevant variables

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I found that my problem was not with the ComboBox. It was what the ComboBox was filled with. The code was expecting a certain value to be there but it was filled with something else.

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

This question should not have a vb6 tag. - Unlike VBA, Vb6 only has single column comboboxes.